# Combining CSS descendant and class selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a convenient way to combine descendant selectors for a class that doesn't clutter the space much?

For example, I have two rules:

```
.details-recommendations-table th:nth-child(1) { /*rule*/ }
.details-recommendations-table td:nth-child(1) { /*rule*/ }
```

as the rules are the same, and describe some `td` and `th` elements within a class, it would be handy to combine them into one. Currently, I have

```
.details-recommendations-table th:nth-child(1), .details-recommendations-table td:nth-child(1) { /*rule*/ }
```

but that just clutters the space by repeating the name of the parent class. Is there a neat way to combine these rules, something along the lines of:

```
.details-recommendations-table th:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(1) { /*rule*/ }
```

The above doesn't work as the `td:nth-child(1)` part propagates to other tables, i.e. it doesn't apply only to `td` elements within the `.details-recommendations-table` class, as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `td` and `th` elements are validly placed within a `tr` element, you can simply condense your selector to:

```css
.details-recommendations-table tr :nth-child(1) { /*rule*/ }
```

If, however, you're wanting to pull the first of each type (regardless of which nth child they are), you can use:

```css
.details-recommendations-table tr :nth-of-type(1) { /*rule*/ }
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/R9jKk/).

In both cases this assumes that your `td` and `th` elements have no children. If they do have children, you should introduce a [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) (`>`):

```css
.details-recommendations-table tr > :nth-of-type(1) { /*rule*/ }
```

Comment: This works for the specific case of descendants and does answer my question. Is there a general way to combine different rules in one? I.e. two different elements, such as `.details-recommendations-table span, .details-recommendations-table div` into something like `.details-recommendations-table <<span, div>>` where `<< >>` would represent some kind of grouping? Writing `.details-recommendations-table span, div` would make the rule applicable to all divs... I'm after a neat way to clean up the stylesheet. Without using `less.js` to nest things.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested and fixed it now, according to the comment left by `BoltClock's a Unicorn`:

```
.details-recommendations-table :not(tr):not(tbody):nth-child(1) { /* rule */ }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ym9Va/

Comment: That would match `tbody` if there is one (and there usually is).

Answer (score 0):

This will select any first child right beneath the tr:

```
.details-recommendations-table tr>*:nth-child(1) { /*rule*/ }
```